# C# WPF ItemsControl item moving animation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a little question about animation in ItemsControl 
I have this XAML code

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CellItems}" Background="Black">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">

                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiplierConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="J"></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.ItemSize" ElementName="ThisControl"></Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiplierConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="I"></Binding>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.ItemSize" ElementName="ThisControl"></Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Width="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl, Path=DataContext.ItemSize}"
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl, Path=DataContext.ItemSize}"
                    Style="{StaticResource CellItemBorderStyle}">
                <Border.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
                                  Command="{Binding DataContext.MoveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </Border.InputBindings>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl, Path=DataContext.ItemSize, Converter={StaticResource SingleMultiplierConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.4}"
                           Style="{StaticResource CellItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

CellItems is a property in my ViewModel

```
    public List<CellItem> CellItems { get; set; }
```

CellItem is my class:

```
public class CellItem : ViewModelBase
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    private int i;
    public int I
    {
        get { return this.i; }
        set
        {
            this.i = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.I));
        }
    }

    private int j;
    public int J
    {
        get { return this.j; }
        set
        {
            this.j = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.J));
        }
    }

}
```

I and J properties is binding in ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle you can see 
**How can I do animation when I change I(or J) property?**

Please feel free to ask me more details 
Thank you!

UPDATED
When I click on items they are moving but without animation.
I need to realize the moving with animation but I don't know how to... DoubleAnimation,Storyboard?..
[image: this]

Comment: Don't know how to do what? What _specifically_ are you having trouble with? When or how to trigger the animation? How to implement the animation itself? Please simplify your code so that you have a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, and provide a precise description of what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Answer (score -1):

Just to be clear here, you are trying to start an animation when a property changes? Implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise an event which will start the animation in your ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Not sure that I understand you. Can you give me any examples?